# Hash table of class hierarchy

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have the following situation:

```
class A {
public:
 int a;

 // Just for RTTI
 virtual ~A() = default;
}

class B : public A {
public:
 int b;
}
```

And then I create an `std::unordered_map<int, A>`, where I want to be able to store both `A`s and `B`s, and get back to their original representation.

I always know whether the element corresponds to an `A` or a `B` from context at the point of `find()` by looking just at the key.

However, if I run the following program:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class A {
public:
 int a{};

 A() = default;
 A(int a) : a(a){}

 // Just for RTTI
 virtual ~A() = default;
};

class B : public A {
public:
 B(int a, int b) : A(a), b(b) {}
 int b;
};


int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, A> m;
    m[1] = A(4);
    m[2] = B(2,5);

    if (dynamic_cast<B *>(&m.at(2)) == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "FAIL!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I get a "FAIL" printed in my screen. This was not the behavior I expected; how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've run into is [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) -- in particular, your `unordered_set<int, A>` is able to contain objects of type A only.  When you try to place an object of type `B` into it, it compiles, but only the superclass-part of the `B` object is actually copied into the data structure -- the subclass part (i.e. the part of the `B` object that is not part of the `A` superclass) is "sliced off" and discarded, and what is stored in the set is just another `A`.

If you want your `unordered_set` to contain values of different subclasses, then the only way to do it is to store the value-objects indirectly via some sort of pointer, instead; for example, you could use a `unordered_set<int, A*>` instead, or better yet a `unordered_set<int, shared_ptr<A> >` (so that you'll be protected from memory leaks).  Then you'll need to allocate each A/B object on the heap before inserting it into the set.

(An alternative approach would be to keep a separate `unordered_set` for each subclass, e.g. have a `unordered_set<int, A>` *and* a `unordered_set<int, B>`.  Of course the downside to that is it complicates your calling code)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone runs into this in the future, another road you can take is to use `std::variant` and keep the single hash table without -at least directly- using pointers as Jeremy suggested.